# Create a Form with 2 entities in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

How to create a form with 2 entities
I have 2 entities:

Entity/Cliente.php

```
class Cliente
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idcliente", type="integer")
     */
    private $idcliente;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nombre;

     /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set idcliente
     *
     * @param integer $idcliente
     *
     * @return Cliente
     */
    public function setIdcliente($idcliente)
    {
        $this->idcliente = $idcliente;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idcliente
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdcliente()
    {
        return $this->idcliente;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     *
     * @return Cliente
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

Entity/Contacto.php

```
class Contacto
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idcliente", type="integer")
     */
    private $idcliente;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set idcliente
     *
     * @param integer $idcliente
     *
     * @return Contacto
     */
    public function setIdcliente($idcliente)
    {
        $this->idcliente = $idcliente;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idcliente
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdcliente()
    {
        return $this->idcliente;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     *
     * @return Contacto
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

I would like to create one form to enter the following data:

nombre (nombre in Cliente entity)

nombre (nombre in Contacto entity)

idcliente (idcliente in Contacto entity)(same stored value that the client entity)

Comment: Does `$idcliente` refer to the `Cliente`? If so, you need so start thinking in terms of objects, not database ID's. So `Contacto` has a `Cliente`, not simply an "id". It's a bit unclear from your example what you are trying to do - perhaps a diagram would be of some help?

Comment: @iLikeBreakfast any solutions for if? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idcliente is unique

[Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW2lG.png)

My concept of form in twig is so:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<p>Nombre: {{ form_widget(form.nombre) }}</p>
<p>Nombre Contacto: {{ form_widget(form.nombrecontacto) }}</p>
{{ form_widget(form.Guardar) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My concept in controller is so:

```
public function inicioAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $clientes  = $em->createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT CLI.idcliente
                        FROM GeneralBundle:Cliente CLI
                        WHERE CLI.idcliente = CON.idcliente)->getResult();
        $numclientes = count($clientes);
        $idnew = $numclientes+1;
        $cliente = new Cliente();
        $contacto = new Contacto();

        $form = $this->createform(**¿¿ Here is the question ??**); 

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $cliente->setIdcliente($idnew);
            $em->persist($cliente);
            $em->flush();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $contacto->setIdcliente($idnuevo);
            $em->persist($contacto);
        }
    }
```